# Regex findall returning tuple of substrings instead of just the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
>>> regex = r'((?:\+|00)[17](?: |\-)?|(?:\+|00)[1-9]\d{0,2}(?: |\-)?|(?:\+|00)1\-\d{3}(?: |\-)?)?(0\d|\([0-9]{3}\)|[1-9]{0,3})(?:((?: |\-)[0-9]{2}){4}|((?:[0-9]{2}){4})|((?: |\-)[0-9]{3}(?: |\-)[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{7}))'
>>> re.findall(regex, "some text")
[]
>>> re.findall(regex, "phone: +447825492609")
[('+447', '82', '', '', '', '5492609')]
```

Why am I getting the result like this? Instead of:

```
['+447825492609']
```

Comment: You have match groups in parentheses. So it is returning all matched groups.

Comment: What should be the correct expression then?

Comment: Try this: `(?:(?:\+|00)[17](?: |\-)?|(?:\+|00)[1-9]\d{0,2}(?: |\-)?|(?:\+|00)1\-\d{3}(?: |\-)?)?(?:0\d|\(?:[0-9]{3}\)|[1-9]{0,3})(?:(?:(?: |\-)[0-9]{2}){4}|(?:(?:[0-9]{2}){4})|(?:(?: |\-)[0-9]{3}(?: |\-)[0-9]{4})|(?:[0-9]{7}))`